# How to make an error to be shown underneath your input

Tags: jquery

I need to make a contact form that informs you if you are filling it in correctly for a school project, this is my js:

```
      $("#name").change(function(){

        if (!$("#name").val()){
            $("p#succes1").hide();
            $("p#error1").show();
        }
        else{
            $("p#succes1").show();
            $("p#error1").hide(); 
        }
       })
```

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are asking us about, given that you have not provided any html related to the script you provided, and your script is not attempting to set any message on the page.

Comment: do you want error to be shown when the #name is empty?

Comment: What is the current result and what do you want to achieve? You need to make it clear in your question so people can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the length of the input then decide what to do based on the condition outcome.

```
$("#name").change(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val().length;
    if (name > 0){
    $("p#succes1").show();
    $("p#error1").hide();
    }
    else {
    $("p#succes1").hide();
    $("p#error1").show();
    }
```

Comment: A length of 0 is falsy.  An empty string value `''` is also falsy, and has a length of 0.  Both checking `!val()` and `length < 1` are the same thing

Comment: You're saying this fixes the problem.  But this performs effectively the same conditional, with the order reversed.  So it's unclear how performing the same logic solves any problem.

Comment: is !$("#name").val() and $("#name").val() == "" the same?

Comment: OP logic.  If `!val()`, hide the success and show the error.  So if the value is `''` it will hide the success, and show the error.  Now your logic.  If the length is 0, hide the success and show the error.  A length of 0, means the value is `''`.  There is literally zero difference in the outcome of your logic vs the OP logic.

Comment: yes `!$("#name").val()` and `$("#name").val() == ""` both return true, if the value is empty

Comment: Pop open your developer tools and go to your console.  Type `!''` and hit enter.  and type `'' == ''` and hit enter.  Both are true.

Comment: I have not seen ! ' ' before. Thought that was the problem. Thanks for the new lesson.